# How to efficiently shuffle numpy array in chunks

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array that looks like the following [-1,0,1,0,1,2,1,2,3,...,n-1,n,n+1,n,n+1,n+2..]
I would like to shuffle the array in chunks of 3, is there an efficient way to do it in numpy?

I know you can shuffle a numpy array using the following shuffle method, but this gives me a fully shuffled array. Is there a way to shuffle it in chunks in numpy?

```
import numpy.random as rng

ind = numpy.arange(100)
rng = numpy.random.RandomState(123)
rng.shuffle(ind)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Reshape into 3 columns.  [`shuffle`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.shuffle.html) doc says it just shuffles the 1st dimension:

```
ind=np.arange(99)  # multple of 3
ind=ind.reshape(-1,3)
rng.shuffle(ind)
ind.flatten()
```

Comment: To keep the array flattened after the process, shouldn't the last operation be ind = ind.flatten()?

Comment: Right.  `flatten` isn't an inplace operation.  I adapted the code snippet from an interactive session, where I got an automatic print of the last line.